# I'm working on a Windows 7 desktop gadget and cannot get it to display in the sidebar

Tags: windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have created a desktop gadget for Windows 7. I placed the .gadget file in the Program Files/Windows Sidebar/Gadgets folder. I placed the necessary xml and html files in the .gadget file. How do I get it to show up in the gadget sidebar? I have followed the instructions on the Windows website but am getting nowhere.